# vb.net display oldest date

Tags: vb.net, data-conversion

Book Collection as a coding project for an intro class and need to display the oldest print year. It is showing up initially but won't write to file because I'm trying to convert from string to integer. Code that's being used:

```
Private Sub findOldest()
    Dim oldest As Integer = 4000
    Dim printDate As Integer
    For index As Integer = 2 To count * 4 - 1 Step 4
        printDate = CInt(bookData(index))
        If oldest > printDate Then
            oldest = printDate
        End If
    Next
    lblOldestBook.Text = CStr(oldest)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code of writing to file? What bookdata function does?

Comment: Please include all the code we need to be able to duplicate your problem - Have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to return the earliest date. As for writing to the `.Text` property, you can use [.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) to represent in object as a string.

```
Dim MinDate = (From d In bookData).Min() 'untested!

lblOldestBook.Text = oldest.ToString()
```